# Recieving several 'type is not assignable to parameter' and 'property missing in type' errors in Angular2 Form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I created a large questionnaire that isn't loading data for some reason.  I didn't get any errors in the console so I closed the node session and restarted to see if it would throw errors or load right up.  Sure enough it has an entire list of errors.

> src/app/questionnaire/questionnaire.component.ts(65,21): error TS2345: Argument of type 'QuestionSection[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QuestionSection'.
>
> src/app/questionnaire/questionnaire.component.ts(65,21): error TS2345: Argument of type 'QuestionSection[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QuestionSection'. Property 'name' is missing in type 'QuestionSection[]'.
>
> src/app/questionnaire/questionnaire.component.ts(69,22): error TS2339: Property
>   'sections' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'.
>
> src/app/questionnaire/questionnaire.component.ts(74,60): error TS2339: Property
>   'questions' does not exist on type 'QuestionSection[]'.
>
> src/app/questionnaire/questionnaire.component.ts(192,22): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'QuestionSection'.

I'm mainly getting those errors over and over in every instance they occur as well as a few other properties "missing" that are actually there.  Again this is happened when starting the app in Node.

Here's my code

`question-primative.ts`

```
export interface QuestionPrimative {
    question    : string;
    id          : string;
    name        : string;
    formctrl?   : string;
    formgrp?    : string;
    lowExtreme? : string;
    hiExtreme?  : string;
    template    : string;
}
```

`answer.ts`

```
export interface Answer {
    answer      : string;
    id          : string;
    trigger?    : string;
    formctrl?   : string;
}
```

`question-base.ts`

```
import { QuestionPrimative }    from './question-primative';
import { Answer }               from './answer';

export interface QuestionBase extends QuestionPrimative {
    answers?    : Answer[];
}
```

`micro-question.ts`

```
import { Question } from './question';

export interface MicroQuestions {
    activate?   : string;
    childgroup? : string;
    questions?  : Question[];
}
```

`question.ts`

```
import { QuestionBase }     from './question-base';
import { MicroQuestions }   from './micro-questions';

export interface Question extends QuestionBase {
    micros?     : MicroQuestions[];
}
```

`question-section.ts`

```
import { Question } from './question';

export interface QuestionSection {
    name        : string;
    questions   : Question[];
}
```

`questionnaire.ts`

```
import { QuestionSection }  from './question-section';

export interface Questionnaire{
    sections: QuestionSection[];
}
```

`questionnaire.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit,
         OnChanges }                from '@angular/core';

import { Response, Http }           from '@angular/http';

import { QuestionSection }          from '../data-types/question-section';
import { Question }                 from '../data-types/question';
import { Answer }                   from '../data-types/answer';
import { MicroQuestions }           from '../data-types/micro-questions';
import { Questionnaire }            from '../data-types/questionnaire';

import { Observable }               from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { QuestionService }          from './question-service/question-service';

import { FormBuilder, FormControl,
         FormGroup, FormArray }     from '@angular/forms';



@Component({

    moduleId    : module.id,
    selector    : 'questionnaire-page',
    templateUrl : './questionnaire.component.html',
    providers   : [ QuestionService ]
})

export class QuestionnairePage implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    Data: Questionnaire;
    Questionnaire: FormGroup;



    constructor(private _qs: QuestionService, private fbuild: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._qs.getData().subscribe( data =>  { this.Data = data; });

        this.createQuestionnaire();
    }

    ngOnChanges(){
        //this.patchQuestionnaire();
        //console.log(this.Questionnaire.value);
        //this.createQuestionnaire();
    }

    createQuestionnaire(){
        this.Questionnaire = this.fbuild.group({
            sections: this.fbuild.array([])
        });
        //this.createSection();
        this.setSections( this.Data ? this.Data.sections: [] );  //line 65
    }

    createSection(){
        this.Questionnaire.sections = this.fbuild.group({
            name        : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.name: '',
            questions   : this.fbuild.array([])
        });
        //this.createQuestion();
        this.setSectionQuestions( this.Data.sections ? this.Data.sections.questions: [] ); // line 74
    }

    createQuestion(){
        this.Questionnaire.sections.questions = this.fbuild.group({ //line 69
            question    : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.question: '',
            id          : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.id: '',
            name        : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.name: '',
            formctrl    : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.formctrl: '',
            formgroup   : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.formgroup: '',
            loextreme   : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.loextreme: '',
            hiextreme   : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.hiextreme: '',
            template    : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.template: '',
            answers     : this.fbuild.array([]),
            micros      : this.fbuild.array([])
        });
        //this.createAnswer();
        //this.createMicroSection();
        this.setAnswers( this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.answers: [] );
        this.setMicroSections( this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros: [] );
    }

    createAnswer(){
        this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.answers = this.fbuild.group({
            answer      : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.answers.answer: '',
            id          : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.answers.id: '',
            trigger     : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.answers.trigger: '',
            formctrl    : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.answers.formctrl: ''
        });
    }

    createMicroSection(){
        this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.micros = this.fbuild.group({
            activate    : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.activate: '',
            questions   : this.fbuild.array([])
        });
        //this.createMicroQuestions();
        this.setMicroQuestionMicros(
            this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.questions.micros: []
        );
    }

    createMicroQuestions(){
        this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.micros.questions = this.fbuild.group({
            question    : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.question: '',
            id          : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.id: '',
            name        : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.name: '',
            formctrl    : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.formctrl: '',
            formgroup   : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.formgroup: '',
            loextreme   : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.loextreme: '',
            hiextreme   : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.hiextreme: '',
            template    : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.template: '',
            answers     : this.fbuild.array([]),
            micros      : this.fbuild.array([])
        });
        this.setMicroQuestionAnswers(
            this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.questions.answers:[]
        );
        this.setMicroQuestionMicros(
            this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.questions.micros:[]
        );
    }

    get sectionLoad(): FormArray {
        return this.Questionnaire.get('sections') as FormArray;
    }

    addSection(){
        let adg = this.fbuild.group(new QuestionSection());
        this.sectionLoad.push(adg);
        //this.addSectionQuestion();
    }

    setSections(sections: QuestionSection){
        let sdg = sections.map(section => this.fbuild.group(section)); // line 192
        let sda = this.fbuild.array(sdg);
        this.Questionnaire.setControl('sections', sda);
    }



    get sectionQuestionLoad(): FormArray {
        return this.Questionnaire.sections.get('questions') as FormArray;
    }

    addSectionQuestion(){
        let sqg = this.fbuild.group(new Question());
        this.sectionQuestionLoad.push(sqg);
    }

    setSectionQuestions(questions: Question){
        let sqg = questions.map(question => this.fbuild.group(question));
        let sqa = this.fbuild.array(sqg);
        this.Questionnaire.sections.setControl('questions', sqa);
    }



    get answerLoad(): FormArray {
        return this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.get('answers') as FormArray;
    }

    addAnswer(){
        let aag = this.fbuild.group(new Answer());
        this.answerLoad.push(aag);
    }

    setAnswers(answers: Answer){
        let sag = answers.map(answer => this.fbuild.group(answer));
        let saa = this.fbuild.array(sag);
        this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.setControl('answers', saa);
    }



    get microSectionsLoad(): FormArray{
        return this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.get('micros') as FormArray;
    }

    addMicroSection(){
        let ams = this.fbuild.group(new MicroQuestions());
        this.microSectionsLoad.push(ams);
    }

    setMicroSections(micros: MicroQuestions){
        let msg = micros.map(micro => this.fbuild.group(micro));
        let msa = this.fbuild.array(msg);
        this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.micros.setControl(msa);
    }

    get microQuestionAnswerLoad(): FormArray{
        return this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.micros.questions.get('answers') as FormArray;
    }

    addMicroQuestionAnswers(){
        let mag = this.fbuild.group(new Answer());
        this.microQuestionAnswerLoad.push(mag);
    }

    setMicroQuestionAnswers(answers: Answer){
        let qag = answers.map(answer => this.fbuild.group(answer));
        let qaa = this.fbuild.array(qag);
        this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.micros.questions.answers.setControl(qaa);
    }

    get microQuestionMicroLoad(): FormArray{
        return this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.micros.questions.get('micros') as FormArray;

    }

    addMicroQuestionMicros(){
        let msm = this.fbuild.group(new Question());
        this.microQuestionMicroLoad.push(msm);

    }

    setMicroQuestionMicros(mq: MicroQuestions){
        let mqg = mq.map(microq => this.fbuild.group(microq));
        let mqa = this.fbuild.array(mqg);
        this.Questionnaire.sections.questions.micros.questions.micros.setControl(mqa);
    }
}
```

As you see in the commented parts of my code I was playing around with the way things load figuring maybe something wasn't generating.  I took a break from making this post to try this

```
//I turned all of my form fields from these.....
question    : this.Data ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.question: '',

//to these.
question    : this.Data.sections.questions.micros ? this.Data.sections.questions.micros.question: '',
```

I went directly to the outermost element for each field and I still got the same list of errors in Node.  Does anybody know why the properties aren't being found in my `interface`s or n the form?  I haven't even bothered binding to html yet though the way I have it setup going strait to `Data` everything works perfectly, so I'm assuming once I get this issue resolved and go through binding the formgroups and controls it should work.  For now I just need to know why this is happening.  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

I just changed the `Questionnaire` interface's name to `QuestionnaireType` just to make sure it doesn't get confused with the `Questionnaire` variable in the class, still getting same chain of errors in Node though.

Comment: the stacktrace is clear i guess you cannot assign a object to an array , you need to push to a array

Comment: I don't understand, how am I not already pushing to an array?

Comment: Can you highlight the lines in your code where you are getting error?

Comment: ok I just commented where they are.